# NHibernate Criteria restriction with database-executed SHA1?

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

Is it possible to convert this sort of query:

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE SHA1(field1 + field2) = 'hash';
```

into NHibernate's Criteria language? E.g., something like:

```
session.CreateCriteria<Car>()
    .Add(Expression.Eq("SHA1(field1 + field2)", "hash"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this answer will work for you?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/797243

I would try something like:

```
ISQLFunction sqlAdd = new VarArgsSQLFunction("(", "+", ")");
var concat = Projections.SqlFunction(sqlAdd, NHibernateUtil.String, Projections.Property("ObjectProperty1"), Projections.Property("ObjectProperty2"));
var sha1 = Projections.SqlFunction("SHA1", NHibernateUtil.String, concat);
...
session.CreateCriteria<Car>().Add(Expression.Eq(sha1, "hash"));
```