# NHibernate LIKE query on date column

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, nhibernate, sql-like

I'm using the following code to dynamically filter data (I'm using MySQL as a DB engine):

```cs
var filter = string.Empty;
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filterNumber))
{
    filter = "t.Number LIKE :filterNumber";
}
var query = string.Format("SELECT t FROM Table t WHERE 1=1 AND {0} ORDER BY {1} {2}", filter, orderBy, orderDirection);
var q = Session.CreateQuery(query);
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filterNumber))
{
    q.SetParameter<string>("filterNumber", "%" + filterNumber + "%");
}
q.SetFirstResult(offset);
q.SetMaxResults(limit);
return q.List<Table>();
```

(assume that `filterNumber`, `orderBy`, `orderDirection`, `offset` and `limit` are method's parameters and `1=1` was added only for the sake of this question so the query always work)

It does work when Number is a string (VARCHAR in MySQL) column but it does not work when it is a datetime or integer column.

For datetime it raises the exception:
`could not execute query […] Name:filterDate - Value:%2012%` and inner exception is `Specified cast is not valid`.

For integer/float columns the exception is:
`could not execute query […] Name:filterPrice - Value:%100%` and inner exception is `Input string was not in a correct format`.

(`Date` and `Price` are another columns in the table)

How to dynamically create such a LIKE query on date/numbers columns? This kind of query works well in MySQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE `Date` LIKE '%2012%'
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793166/how-to-user-year-and-month-functions-in-nh-criteria-api

Comment: @nieve I don't have a `Criteria` object and don't know how to transform `IQuery` to it.

Comment: AFAIR it's Session.CreateCriteria method. I can only recommend you to have a look into it, for example here, on Ayende's blog: http://ayende.com/blog/4023/nhibernate-queries-examples

Comment: Cast the column to string before using it in a LIKE-expression.

Comment: @usr This: `filter = "(string)t.Date LIKE :filterDate";` does not work (`Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown. near line 1, column 46`). `filterDate` is already string.

Comment: I don't know NHibernate query syntax but the message sounds like you got the cast syntactically wrong. Probably it is not C# syntax but SQL-style.

Comment: @usr Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @usr comment I managed to do casting in HQL:

```cs
filter = "CAST(t.Date AS String) LIKE :filterDate";
```

It works both for dates and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not such a good idea to use LIKE with dates/numbers if you can avoid it. If the intention is to match on year, you should use the year(alias.property) HQL function (no need to convert your query to the Criteria API, as this is the HQL syntax) and the regular equals operator. Or less/greater than.

I suspect the SQL works through automatic cast to varchar, but unless you really do need pattern matching, I would think this has significantly worse performance compared to working with date extraction or BETWEEN.

If you do need pattern matching, you should cast the date/number to string.